# Trying to use curl to get html from a webpage but the page isn't loading fully

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to count how many streams an artist has on spotify. The closest solution I found is to use the web app (i.e. https://open.spotify.com/artist/2o5jDhtHVPhrJdv3cEQ99Z) and count the streams for the artists 5 most popular songs.

The code below should replicate that website on my server, however the body of the site is missing and I am left with just the skeleton of the site - what am I doing wrong? Also is there a better way to do this? I've looked at the spotify API but it doesn't show how many streams an artist has, I wonder how many sites are getting this information

The relevant PHP code is below:

```
        <?php
        $ch = curl_init('https://open.spotify.com/artist/7Ln80lUS6He07XvHI8qqHH');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36');
        $content = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

My result looks like: https://gyazo.com/c2fde40103280409ce07a37df9bfb77f
It should look like: https://gyazo.com/6b242e27c99cd4b61bab4986524f9cd9

Also, is it possible to have the PHP click on the 'See More' button so that 10 songs are displayed instead? I've had a look through the editor and I can't see where the 5 songs come from as the elements don't exist before

Comment: Surely you might be better using the actual [Spotify API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)?

Comment: Streaming data isn't available on their API, it's a highly requested feature that they haven't added

Comment: OK - never used it but if you look in the dev console at the `DOC` portion of the `Network` tab the first one is the actual page ~ as cited above. The response is very slim - suggesting that the content you want is delivered via js so curl will be of no use. Try `Casper.js` or other headless browser